# Remove image height/width attributes from Image Widget

Tags: widgets, images, customization

The [Image Widget](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/) includes `width` and `height` on the images which I've unsuccessfully have been trying to filter out so I can have fluid width.

I've tried the following, which seems to be the most common solutions for similar problems, in `functions.php`, but without success:

```
function responsive_image_widget( $attr = array() ) {
    unset($attr['width']);
    unset($attr['height']);
    return $attr;
}
add_filter( 'image_widget_image_attributes', 'responsive_image_widget' );
```

and

```
function responsive_image_widget($html) {
  $html = preg_replace('/(width|height)=["\']\d*["\']\s?/', "", $html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('image_widget_image_attributes','responsive_image_widget', 10);
```

Here is a link for the Image Widget's [filter documentation](http://wordpress.org/plugins/image-widget/other_notes/).

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to remove it from attribute filter. When rendering image, plugin is doing as below.

```
$output .= rtrim("<img $hwstring");
foreach ( $attr as $name => $value ) {
  $output .= sprintf( ' %s="%s"', $name, $value );
}
$output .= ' />';
```

It is attaching width and height string beforehand and only applying attribute. Sad thing is that width and height is not kept in attribute filter.

**
I am not sure this should be posted as answer. I posted here because I could not comment in your question.**

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I worked around it by removing it using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting the width and height filters directly?

(from the plugin code)

```
   $instance['width'] = apply_filters( 'image_widget_image_width', abs( $instance['width'] ), $args, $instance );
    $instance['height'] = apply_filters( 'image_widget_image_height', abs( $instance['height'] ), $args, $instance );
```

To use your code as an example:

```
function responsive_image_widget( $currentWidth ) {

   $currentWidth = '';
   return $currentWidth;
}

add_filter('image_widget_image_width', 'responsive_image_widget' );
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this didn't work for me. I "solved" it by removing them with jQuery.

Comment: Ha!  That was my next suggestion. :-)